# How do you organize buckets in Riak?

Tags: namespaces, nosql, organization, riak

Since Riak uses buckets as a way of separating keys, is it possible to have buckets within buckets? If not how would one go about organizing a Riak setup with many buckets for several apps.

The basic problem is how one would go about representing "databases" and "tables" within Riak. Since a bucket translates to a table, what translates to a database?

Namespaces in programming languages usually have hierarchies. It makes sense for Riak buckets to also allow hierarchies, since buckets are essentially namespaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to think about [Riak](http://www.basho.com/products_riak_overview.php) as about very big `key -> value` "table" where [buckets are only prefixes for keys](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/master/src/riak_kv_put_fsm.erl#L158). Now when you know that you can do anything with buckets as long as they are still binary objects.

You can create linear "tables":

```
<<"table1">>
<<"table2">>
```

Or you can create hierarchies:

```
<<"db1.table1">>
<<"db1.table2">>
<<"db2.table1">>
<<"db2.table2">>
```

Or you even can use tuples as buckets:

```
1> term_to_binary({"db1", "table1"}).
<<131,104,2,107,0,3,100,98,49,107,0,6,116,97,98,108,101,49>>
2> term_to_binary({"db1", "table2"}).
<<131,104,2,107,0,3,100,98,49,107,0,6,116,97,98,108,101,50>>
3> term_to_binary({"db2", "table1"}).
<<131,104,2,107,0,3,100,98,50,107,0,6,116,97,98,108,101,49>>
4> term_to_binary({"db2", "table2"}).
<<131,104,2,107,0,3,100,98,50,107,0,6,116,97,98,108,101,50>>
```